# Does MUI formcontrol and textfield do errorvalidation and prevent submit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Do MUI components `FormControl` and `TextField` do error handling for you? In particular prventing a form from being submitted if one of the required `TextFields` is empty. It seems like this is something I need to write on my own, by I wanted to make sure. I know both FormControl and TextField have the `error` prop, but that is only for changing colors.

As an example

```
const state = {
  name: ''
}
const onSubmit = () => {
  if (state.name === '')
     return
  
  fetch(some/api/endpoint)
}

const handleChange = (event) => {
  setState(event.target.value)
}
<Box component="form" onSubmit={obSubmit}>
  <TextField onChange={handleChange} required />
</Box>
```

In the pseudo code above, in the `onSubmit` function I manually check to see if `state.name` is empty and prevent the `onSubmit` from making an API request. The MUI docs keep mentioning error handling, but it seems like it mostly for styling such a red fonts on error but not for checking required values before submitting form.

Is this correct, or does MUI have something that takes care of all this onSubmit validation so I dont have to write my own checks.

Answer (score 0):

Does MUI FormControl and TextField do validation and prevent submit?

Yes and no.

"Yes" because **FormControl** and **TextField** have properties that invoke automatic validation and form submission blocking. However, Material-UI (MUI) is really using **HTML5 built-in validation** to accomplish this.

"No" because without HTML5 built-in validation, no validation occurs. You must implement your own validation by testing input values acquired from callbacks like `onChange`, by blocking form submission with methods like `event.preventDefault()`, by updating the state of components using properties like `error`, and by displaying user feedback text with components like `FormHelperText`.

### MUI uses HTML5 built-in validation

MUI uses component properties like `required` to pass the attribute *required* down to the root HTML5 `<input>` element.

The API Docs for the TextField [required](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/#TextField-prop-required) property say:

> If `true`, the label is displayed as required and the `input` element is required.

This means the *required* attribute is added to `<input>`, activating built-in validation.

You can pass other validation-related attributes (like [max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#max)) down to the HTML5 `<input>` element using the TextField [`inputProps`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/input/#Input-prop-inputProps) property.

TextField has a `type` property that accepts a [valid HTML5 `<input>` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#input_types). This includes `email`, `number` and `url` which come with built-in validation.

### MUI Validation

[MUI validation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#validation) offers a consistent presentation of state among related components.

### HTML5 built-in validation

[HTML5 built-in validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#using_built-in_form_validation) automatically blocks submission of an invalid form and displays user feedback text. It also provides CSS pseudo-classes for you to style elements according to the state of the form. But, since you're using MUI, you can let FormControl and TextField handle the styling for you.